# Java MongoDB POST : 415 unsupported mediatype

Tags: java, mongodb, api, http, http-status-code-415

I am building my first API. The GET request works, but i am stuck at a POST request with error 415 Unsupported mediatype. After some searching and rewriting code, it still fails. Does someone see why? The parameter values are :

```
-String userName 
-String password
-String phone
-String email
-List roles
```

CODE:
UserResource:

```
@RolesAllowed("OWNER")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void create(@PathParam( "userName" ) String userName,@PathParam( "password" ) String password,@PathParam( "phone" ) String phone,@PathParam( "email" ) String email,@PathParam( "roles" ) List<String> roles)
{
User user = new User();
user.setName(userName);
user.setPassword(password);
user.setPhone(phone);
user.setEmail(email);
user.setRoles(roles);
userService.createUser(user);
}
```

UserService:

```
public void createUser(User user){
userDAO.create(user);
}
```

UserDAO:

```
public void create( User user )
{
    save( user );
}
```

the POST request:

```
localhost:8080/User/?userName=Daniel&password=test&phone=0634554567&email=daniel@email.com&roles=["OWNER"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. Omit `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. Your request has nothing whatsoever to do with json.
2. `@PathParam`s should be replaced with `@RequestParam`s. The values are read as request parameters (query string) and not as path parts.

Also, in the request example you should get rid of the extra `/` after `User`:

`localhost:8080/User?userName=Daniel&...`

In order to use path parameters, you should add a path annotation to the resource method configuration, something such as:

`@RequestMapping("/{userName}/{password}/{phone}/{email}/{roles}`

and the request should look something such as:

`localhost:8080/User/Daniel/test/0634554567/daniel/OWNER`

Which is not intuitive at all

And one last thing: `List<String> roles` is wrong. Spring won't convert to a list of strings, no matter if you use path or query parameter. You will have to split the roles into array yourself (probably using `,`as a separator) or supply a `Converter`.